# flash on safari is NOT loading until container div is visible

Tags: flash, safari, load

I have a simple swf in an invisible `<div>`; when user mouseover's the `<div>` becomes visible.

The swf has a `ExternalInterface.addCallback( "..." , ... )` to create connection to js that needs to be called at load, such that by the time user mouseovers the flash-js connection is working.

**PROBLEM:** on windows safari the flash does not go through its loading sequence until the user finally mouseovers ... which is too late.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to leave the div visible at first, let Flash load, then have Flash notify JS that it's time to set it invisible?

Comment: having div visible at load instant, then instantaneously invisibling it  didn't work ... that was my first thought as well.

however, this solved it ( a little hackey ):

actionscript...
on load, call special js handler: ExternalInterface.call("handle_flash_onload",...)

javascript...
function handle_flash_onload()
  { if swf_div is visible ... send play message to flash
  }

so for firefox, when swf loads it immediately sends message to js, but because the user is not mouseover then, the js just ignores the notice.

but for safari, the swf will not instantiate until it is rendered.